# Set value of local iteration scoped variable in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have the below HTML in Angular

```
<span *ngIf="ControllerType?.AttributeID =='Controller Type'">                                            
    <select multiple name="ControllerType.Default" [(ngModel)]="ControllerType1">
        <option *ngFor="let z of ControllerType.Options" value={{z.OptionID}}>
            {{z.OptionID}}
        </option>
    </select>
</span>
```

What I want to know is how can I set `ControllerType.Default` which is of type string to get the values selected in `ControllerType1`. So whatever values were selected and stored in `ControllerType1` should also be stored in `ControllerType.Default`

Doing this `{{ControllerType.Default=ControllerType1;""}}` after the Select tag and inside the iteration just errors out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the expression inside the `ngModelChange`

```
<span *ngIf="ControllerType?.AttributeID =='Controller Type'">
   <select multiple name="ControllerType.Default" [(ngModel)]="ControllerType1"  (ngModelChange)="ControllerType.Default = ControllerType1">
   <option *ngFor="let z of ControllerType.Options" value={{z.OptionID}}>
      {{z.OptionID}}
   </option>
   </select>
</span>
```

updated

create and `ngInit` directive and call it in the HTML

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'ngInit',
  exportAs: 'ngInit'
}) 
export class NgInit {
  @Input() values: any = {};

  @Input() ngInit;
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.ngInit) { this.ngInit(); }
  }  
}
```

assign the expression under ngInit directive

`[ngInit]="ControllerType1 = ControllerType.Default"`

```
  <span [ngInit]="ControllerType1 = ControllerType.Default"  *ngIf="ControllerType?.AttributeID =='Controller Type'">
       <select multiple name="ControllerType.Default" [(ngModel)]="ControllerType1"  (ngModelChange)="ControllerType.Default = ControllerType1">
       <option *ngFor="let z of ControllerType.Options" value={{z.OptionID}}>
          {{z.OptionID}}
       </option>
       </select>
    </span>
```

Comment: very cool..how can I load the value back on page refresh so basically do the opposite {{ControllerType1 = ControllerType.Default}}  so the selected value that were saved gets displayed.

Comment: if you want to keep the values after the page refresh then you need to store if in the localstorage or something and retrieve it at the time page load

Comment: Yeah I am storing it in the DB..ControllerType.Default is how it is stored and is what contains the stored values when page refreshes..but how do I map it to ControllerType1 so it displays on the page.

Comment: in your export class assign ControllerType1 = ControllerType.Default initially

Comment: There are a lot of these select types and then i ll have to do the loop in the export class as well..Is it possible that I can do something like that in the html where I am already iterating.

Comment: Thank you so much for being so awesome and helpful..I am just absolute new to angular and got stuck,,Thanks again for helping out